# System Int 32 help in C#

Tags: c#

I wrote this code in visual studio 2010 and when I compiled it it is giving me this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPB4E.jpg

It is giving me `System.Int32[]` instead of answers when I compile it.. any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Result
    {
        private Random rn = new Random();
        private int[] frequency=new int [7];
        private int face;

        public void rollDice()
        {
            Console.Write("Face\tFrequency\n");
            for (int roll = 1; roll <= 6000; roll++)
            {
                face = rn.Next(1, 7);
            }
            switch (face)
            {
                case 1:
                    frequency[1]++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    frequency[2]++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    frequency[3]++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    frequency[4]++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    frequency[5]++;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    frequency[6]++;
                    break;
            }

        }
        public void display()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < frequency.Length; i++)
                Console.Write("{0}        {1}\n", i, frequency);
                Console.ReadKey();

        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Result rs = new Result();
            rs.rollDice();
            rs.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.Write("{0}        {1}\n", i, frequency);` should be `Console.Write("{0}        {1}\n", i, frequency[i]);`

Comment: and start i from 0

Comment: Why do I have to visit an image on another site to see what your question is all about? => Please include all relevant information directly in your post. If you don't know how to embed images in your question, please check out the Markdown editing help/FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
Console.Write("{0}        {1}\n", i, frequency);
```

With

```
Console.Write("{0}        {1}\n", i, frequency[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void display()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < frequency.Length; i++)
                Console.Write("{0}        {1}\n", i, frequency[i]);
                Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

Comment: Thank You  very much to all who replied to my post.It helps.About image i didn't know how to embed image here.Will embed image in my post directly next time.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects, which is why your project is printing out the `ToString()` code from the parent class, `Object`. If you want to print out the contents residing in the indices of your array, you must directly access each index. You do this while setting your indices in your `switch-case` block, so you would do the same in your `for-loop`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < frequency.Length; i++) {
       Console.Write("{0}        {1}\n", i, frequency[i]);//iterate through the indices
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Some additional points to provide you with better coding experiences down the road:

- Arrays are zero-based, meaning indices start at `0`, not `1`. Please consider refactoring your code to match this practice.
- Use braces everywhere - your for-loop does not contain any, and *could* lead to unexpected results. This is *not* a requirement, but a recommendation.

You can read more on arrays [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).